# For subsets of a n.l.s ,if A is dense in B and B is dense in C. then A is dense in C

Tags: sequences-and-series

I hope I am not using this site incorrectly, I don’t know how to enter the math symbols, so sorry for that. This is a homework question. I have tried to answer the question but have no idea if its correct and given the time of year I have no one to ask.I found this proposition from my notes.

**A** is dense in **B** iff for every **b** an element of **B** there is a sequence (**a**_n) of elements of **A**  s.t  (**a**_n) --> **b** as n--> infinity.

i.e  || **a**-**b**||< $\varepsilon$  for all n>n_0

My ans

|| a - b ||< $\varepsilon$/2 for all n>n_0

and

|| b - c ||< $\varepsilon$/2 for all n>n_0

since **A** is dense in **B** and **B** is dense in **C**

|| a - c || = || a - c + b - b ||

$ || a - c |\le || a - b || + || b - c ||< \varepsilon$

so is **A** is also dense in **C**

Providing this is correct I know how to  prove it in the other direction.

Comment: What does "n.l.s." mean?

Comment: a normed linear space

Answer (score 0):

Let $c \in C$ then since $B$ is dense in $C$ there is a sequence $(b_n)$ of elements in $B$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = c$.
Since $A$ is dense in $B$ we can find a sequence $(a_{nk})$ in $A$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to\infty} a_{nk} = b_n$.
It is not hard to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{nn} = c$, and therefore we found a sequence in $A$ whose limit is $c$, or in other words $A$ is dense in $C$.